# Cannot get a powershell function i created to clear is argument so that it can be called with a different value?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
Function Get-SQLAPICred($user)
{
$inputname = $user + "-name"
$PasswordFile = "\\location\$inputname.txt"
$KeyFile = "\\location\$inputname.key"
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile

return $credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)
}


# This is the start of the first pull, using PSCredential object grabbed from first call to Get-APICred
$GetRecentCSV = Get-ChildItem "\\CSVLocation\" -Name -Filter Report*.CSV | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$PathToCSV = "\\CSVLocation\" + $GetRecentCSV
$PathToOutputCSV = "\\OutputLocation\Output.csv"
$InputArray = Get-Content -Path $PathToCSV | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv
$InputArray = $InputArray | Where-Object {$_.column1 -ne 'XFR'}  
$FilterValues = "'$($InputArray.ID -join "','")'" 
$SQLCred = Get-SQLAPICred -user "username1"
$Query = "SELECT * FROM database
          WHERE Field IN ("+$FilterValues+")
         " 
$UserCSV = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance server\instance -Credential $SQLCred -Database ExtCopy -Query $Query 

# This is the start of the Second pull, using PSCredential object grabbed from first call to Get-APICred
$Uri = 'https://url.to.otherthingapi'
$APICred = Get-SQLAPICred -user "username2"
$RESTTest = Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $DCCred -Uri $Uri
```

The issue I'm having is that the user values stays as "username1" even though I've passed a new argument onto the function. I have toyed with Clear-Variables both inside and outside the function and cannot seem to figure out how to have my function work with ONLY one value passed to it at a time.

Comment: those variable assignments only live in the scope of your `Get-Thing` function. You can use the `$script:` scope identifier to assign them in the script scope, `$script:variable1 =` tho, I wouldn't recommend you go this route. There are always better ways than having a function update the scope of the caller

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear.. at the end of the function i actually have "return $credential = New-Object thingsim doing with this function" which works on the initial call to the function. but when i call the function later with a *new* argument it's either NOT running the function again and simply using the same returned value (based on the initial argument) or its running the function again but not changing the value of the argument give in the second call... does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe if you provide a minimal reproducible example it would be easier to see what you mean.

Comment: 100% we need to know what this is ```return $credential = New-Object thingsim doing with this function``` and how to produce the problem. Seems to me you are returning some kind of object which makes both example not work since get-thing returns answer1,answer2... in the result as you have this written.

Comment: Your function should return an object with at least property `valuethatshouldcontaintheargument`. You do not show what actually goes on in there. [Edit] your question so we can help with your code

Comment: Sorry I was attempting to make this as generic as possible but perhaps I went a bit TOO far.. I will update the main post.

Comment: Well, my first comment still applies, your `$credential` object only lives inside the scope of your `Get-SQLAPICred` function... tho, if you remove the assignment in it, it would work, `$credential =` should not be there!

Comment: my apologies again I AM using the return command with the $credential = line. But regardless. that line would not impact that the PScredential.username object should change each time you pass a new $user argument to the function right?

Comment: You’re not returning that variable. You’re capturing it inside the function and then destroying it when the function ends. Remove that assignment and return as well as it’s not needed. Let the function output the data and you can capture to a variable from *outside* the function

Comment: Understood.. I have changed the function to read:
Function Get-APICred($user)
{
if ($user = 'yubikeyreporting') {$DCUser = $user } else {$DCUser = "SANDIA\" + $user}
$inputname = $user + "-name"
$PasswordFile = "\\snl\css\SQI\Powershell Automation\Run With Other Credentials\Misc\$inputname.txt"
$KeyFile = "\\snl\css\SQI\Powershell Automation\Run With Other Credentials\Misc\$inputname.key"
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile

New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $DCUser, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)
}

Comment: Sadly I get the same result if I output $SQLCred.username OR $DCCred.username.. it comes back with "username1"